# Blocky Diamond Square Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

For my project, I've implemented the Diamond Square algorithm to create a height map for me, but there are some bugs I can't identify in the code.

It seems that ONE value on top of the height map, which ought to have been set by the first square iteration, doesn't get set, causing the black spot, and I can't figure out what causes the blocky appearance of the map either. Unfortunately, since I don't have 10 reputation, I can't post an image of the height map.

Any help is appreciated, and tips on increasing performance would be a great help too.

Code:

```
public static float[,] DiamondSquare(int x, int y)
    {
        //Get the square + 1 size for our algorithm, to be cut down to x,y size at end.
        Point squareSize = FindSquareSize(x,y);

        float[,] squareValues = new float[squareSize.x, squareSize.y];

        //Set the corner values.
        squareValues[0, 0] = 0.5f;
        squareValues[squareSize.x - 1, 0] = 0.5f;
        squareValues[0, squareSize.y - 1] = 0.5f;
        squareValues[squareSize.x - 1, squareSize.y - 1] = 0.5f;


        float variation = 0.5f; //Roughness of the map. Decreases as the algorithm creates the map.
        int level = squareSize.x; //The current chunk the algorithm is working on. Whole, half, quaters, eighths, etc.
        //Debug.Log("Initial level is: " + level);

        //Do the algorithm here.
        while(level > 1)
        {
            int halfstep = level / 2;
            //Debug.Log("Half Step is: " + halfstep);

            //Do Diamond.
            for (int i = halfstep; i < squareSize.x; i += level)
            {
                for (int j = halfstep; j < squareSize.x; j += level)
                {
                    //Bottom left is (0,0)
                    float a = squareValues[i - halfstep, j - halfstep]; //Bottom left.
                    float b = squareValues[i + halfstep, j - halfstep]; //Bottom Right.
                    float c = squareValues[i - halfstep, j + halfstep]; //Top Left.
                    float d = squareValues[i + halfstep, j + halfstep]; //Top Right.

                    float e = ((a + b + c + d) / 4f) + Random.Range(0f, 1f) * variation; //Center

                    squareValues[i, j] = e;

                    //Debug.Log("Did a Diamond!");
                }
            }

            int currentColumn = 0;

            //Do Square.
            for (int i = 0; i < squareSize.x; i += halfstep)
            {
                currentColumn++;
                //If this is an odd column.
                if (currentColumn % 2 == 1)
                {
                    for (int j = halfstep; j < squareSize.y; j += level)
                    {
                        float a, b, c, d, e;

                        bool threePoints = false;

                        try { a = squareValues[i, j + halfstep]; } //Top
                        catch { a = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { b = squareValues[i, j - halfstep]; } //Bottom
                        catch { b = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { c = squareValues[i - halfstep, j]; } //Left
                        catch { c = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { d = squareValues[i + halfstep, j]; } //Right
                        catch { d = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        if (threePoints)
                        {
                            e = ((a + b + c + d) / 3f) + Random.Range(0f, 1f) * variation;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e = ((a + b + c + d) / 4f) + Random.Range(0f, 1f) * variation;
                        }

                        squareValues[i, j] = e;

                        //Debug.Log("Did a Square!");
                    }
                }
                //Else this is an even column.
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < squareSize.y; j += level)
                    {
                        float a, b, c, d, e;

                        bool threePoints = false;

                        try { a = squareValues[i, j + halfstep]; } //Top
                        catch { a = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { b = squareValues[i, j - halfstep]; } //Bottom
                        catch { b = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { c = squareValues[i - halfstep, j]; } //Left
                        catch { c = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        try { d = squareValues[i + halfstep, j]; } //Right
                        catch { d = 0; threePoints = true; }

                        if (threePoints)
                        {
                            e = ((a + b + c + d) / 3f) + Random.Range(0f, 1f) * variation;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e = ((a + b + c + d) / 4f) + Random.Range(0f, 1f) * variation;
                        }

                        squareValues[i, j] = e;

                        //Debug.Log("Did a Square!");
                    }
                }
            }

            //Reduce range and variation.
            level /= 2;
            variation /= 2;

        }
```

Comment: Tip for increasing performance: Less try/catches and more bounds checking. Don't rely on exceptions to make sure you are in an array.